# Debugging techniques to troubleshoot angularjs controller not being initialised

Tags: angularjs

I've run into an issue with an angular app I'm working on. I've defined a controller which adds one variable to the scope. After the page loads, I can see that the scope doesn't have the variable - when I try to inspect it in chrome dev tools, it returns an undefined. I've put a break point in the controller code which initialises the variable and I can see that it is not being hit. I've checked for javascript errors and there are none.

But now I'm stuck - I don't know how to proceed with debugging this issue. Why would a controller that has been specified on the page with an ng-controller directive not be initialised? And what techniques are available for debugging such an issue?

Update: I've already tried batarang - doesn't help. The moment I try to enable inspection in batarang, it reloads the page. I'm able to inspect the scope using techniques specified in ng-book (https://www.ng-book.com/p/Debugging-AngularJS/) but I'm still not making much headway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured out the problem: There were 2 issues:

1. angular auto bootstrap - there were two nested elements in the DOM which were trying to do auto bootstrap. This is not supported according to the documentation.
2. the angular bootstrap was kicking in before the DOM had finished loading.

So we used requirejs' domready plugin to defer angular bootstrapping till the dom is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Try the chrome extension Batarang, it extends developer tools. Its handy for debugging scopes, models & dependencies.

https://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang/

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk

**UpDate:**

Just found this, javascript stack trace `Spy-js`:

https://github.com/spy-js/spy-js

http://spy-js.com/

Comment: Doesn't help. I'd already tried batarang before, it just reloads the page the moment I try to enable inspection. Either something wrong with the chrome-batarang version I'm using or something wrong with the page. Also, what I want to know is why the controller was not run when the page loaded. I can see from the javascript console that the controller has not been run - because a variable that should've been set was not set. Is it possible to use Batarang to debug such an issue? If so how?